# How can I center text in a button component using styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have made a button component using styled-components like below.
And I am using this button component in another component, even made a parent  component to the button component, hoping that if the parent component has "text-align: center" attribute, it'd center texts in my button, which turned out not... maybe I did not do it right?

Below is my code for Button.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

const colorStyles = css`
  ${(props) =>
    props.color === "blue" &&
    css`
      background: #588ced;
      color: #ffffff;

      &:hover {
        background: #3866bc;
      }
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.color === "gray" &&
    css`
      background: #eeeef2;
      color: #65636a;

      &:hover {
        background: #dbdadf;
      }
    `}
`;

const sizeStyles = css`
  ${(props) =>
    props.size === "normal" &&
    css`
      width: 181px;
      height: 48px;
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.size === "small" &&
    css`
      width: 100px;
      height: 40px;
    `}
`;

const shapeStyles = css`
  ${(props) =>
    props.shape === "round" &&
    css`
      border-radius: 50px;
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.shape === "squared" &&
    css`
      border-radius: 10px;
    `}
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  /* common styles */
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  /* sizes */
  ${sizeStyles}

  /* colors */
  ${colorStyles}

  /* shapes */
  ${shapeStyles}

  /* etc */
  // & + & {
  //   margin-left: 1rem;
  // }
`;

function Button({ children, color, size, shape, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <StyledButton color={color} size={size} shape={shape} {...rest}>
          {children}
        </StyledButton>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

AND this is a part from the other component where the button component is used.

```
import styles from "./Page.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Button from "../button/Button";

export default function Page({ data, setModalVisibleState }) {
  const addButtonHandler = () => {
    setModalVisibleState(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.titleBox}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGraduationCap} />
        <p>{data.title}</p>
        <div className={styles.buttonWrap}>
          <Button size="normal" shape="squared" color="blue" onClick={addButtonHandler}>{data.button}</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
//...and more...
```

And under "./Page.module.css" I have done this.

```
.buttonWrap {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This is how my buttons look right now. Before I used **text-align** and **align-items** attributes the text was located on the upper left side of the button. Is there an way to center texts in the button?

[image]

I am wondering if the purple box on the right has anything to do with centering the text..

[image]

Thank you very much in advance for reading and kindly answering my question.  :)

Comment: Please add a sandbox (codesandbox etc), especially in CSS questions. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add: `justify-content: center;` [Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

> To center our box we use the `align-items` property to align our item on the cross axis, which in this case is the block axis running vertically. We use `justify-content` to align the item on the main axis, which in this case the inline axis running horizontally.

### DEMO

```css
button{
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #588ced;
  color: #ffffff;
  width:189px;
  height:48px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button style="justify-content: center;">button</button>
```

Comment: I have tried justify-content: center; but in another component... Again, thank you very much!